# ADA development environment 2017

Tags: eclipse-plugin, ada

I would like to install an ADA development environment, possibly in Eclipse but it seems to me that no plugin is available for download from eclipse market place, 
no download is truly available from 
https://libre.adacore.com/download/
so, what happens, did ADA die?
I think not, but why it is so difficult also just install a development environment?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The downloads from the [Libre](https://libre.adacore.com/download/) site include AdaCore’s own IDE "GPS".

I don’t know whether AdaCore’s professional customers can get *GNATbench*, their Eclipse plugin, last heard of in 2014 or thereabouts. They don’t provide it on their [Github](https://github.com/AdaCore) pages.

It looks to me as though they use GPS themselves (there are quite a few GPS plugins). Some other Ada developers (myself included) use Emacs.

Comment: Thanks, now https://libre.adacore.com/download/ works and it is a simple installation, I prefer Eclipse but I will survive also with GPS.